# Medium Voltage Cables

Tags: high-voltage, cables

Concerning medium voltage cables, 12/20 kV, 50 Hz I would like to ask two questions

1)What is the difference between these two types of cables:

- N2XSY
- N2XS2Y

As far I know the difference is the overstealth. N2XSY has PVC overstealth while N2XS2Y has PE overstealth. In which applications should we choose one type over the other.

2. Also there are those types of cables:

- N2XS(F)2Y that includes a water blocking powder
- N2XS(FL)2Y with water blocking powder and aluminium tape

When those two types of cables should be used over the classic one (N2XSY).

Comment: the word is not `overstealth`

Comment: Do you mean 'oversheath' or 'outer sheath'? Sheat = a protective covering around an electric cable.

Comment: Consult seller recommendations.